# Missing artifact org.apache.camel:camel-xmljson - JBOSS

Tags: java, maven, jboss, dependencies

I'm trying develop my first switchyard application whatching that tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gd8goj-Uj_U

When i try add org.apache.camel to de dependencies and i got that error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTswF.png

Regards, Agostinho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your 'pom.xml' file. There you have all dependencies. You must define a repositories to download all those 'jars'.
If there are no jar in defined repositories (or another version of library) the 'jars' will not be downloaded. You can use search through some repository to find your library.

For example the definition of repositories in 'pom.xml' file:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net</id>
            <url>http://search.maven.org/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
...
        </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Thanks, worked.
This is the problem they cant find de version and i need to add repository :)